# How can I specify time for text titles in iMovie for iOS

Tags: editing, imovie, iphone, ios

I have iMovie on my iPhone 5S so **my question is specifically for iMovie on iOS**. I am trying to put together a video and want to add a text object to it. However, I want it to begin X seconds into the video last for Y seconds. I haven't been able to find how to specify that in iMovie for iOS. The only options are Opening, Middle and End. But I want to specify it when to begin and how long to last - the available options really only let me display the text for the entire clip.

I know I can do this in iMovie for my desktop iMac where all the clips and text object can be dragged to a certain length; that's basically the functionality I'm looking for. Is that not available in iMovie for iOS?

Answer (score 4):

If you click on the "?" in the upper right, you'll get yellow markers that show help. One of them is "Learn More" where it brings up the user manual and a search field. When I type "titles" into the search field, it gives me a list of options, the first of which was "Add a title."

According to that help section, a title lasts the entire length of the video or still you apply it to.

So, you can cut your video into 3 pieces - the piece before the title, the piece containing the title, and the piece after the title. To do that:

1. click on the clip and scroll to the time where you want the title to start
2. press the scissors icon at the bottom. This will offer some options.
3. Click on "Split"

Do the process again where you want the title to end.

Once you've done that, click on the piece you want to contain the title. At the bottom, click on the "T" icon. That will bring up the title selection tool. Choose your title style and click on the text to edit it.